# PHP Guzzle with basic auth and bearer token

Tags: php, guzzle6

I'm trying to make a connection with infojobs-api, the documentation explian how to make it in this way:

> GET /api/1/application HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.infojobs.net
>       Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==,Bearer 07d18fac-77ea-461f-9bfe-a5e9d98deb3d

(https://developer.infojobs.net/documentation/user-oauth2/index.xhtml)

And this is my code:

```
$basicauth = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.infojobs.net']);

$credentials = base64_encode(CLIENT_ID .':' . CLIENT_SECRET ) ;

$newresponse = $basicauth->request(
  'GET',
  'api/1/curriculum',
  ['debug' => true], 
  ['auth' => 
    ['Basic', $credentials] ,
    ['Bearer', $acceso->access_token]
  ]
)->getBody()->getContents();

d($newresponse);
```

The API/Guzlle give me back this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://api.infojobs.net/api/1/curriculum` resulted in a `401 No Autorizado` response:
>   {"error":"102","error_description":"Client credentials not valid","timestamp":"2016-06-25T14:08:54.774Z"}
>    in /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:107

So I'm doing something wrong, but I don't find what it's wrong.

Any idea, thanks.

Oskar

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As I'm seeing your request's HTTP headers:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==,Bearer 07d18fac-77ea-461f-9bfe-a5e9d98deb3d
```

You have an `Authorization` header which contains a comma separated value. They are not apart from each other. So you can't benefit from Guzzle's `auth` key like what you have done.

What you should do is setting Authorization header manually:

```
$newresponse = $basicauth->request(
    'GET',
    'api/1/curriculum',
    ['debug'   => true], 
    ['headers' => 
        [
            'Authorization' => "Basic {$credentials},Bearer {$acceso->access_token}"
        ]
    ]
)->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: In my case I only had to add `Authorization => Bearer {$token}` and I also had to change `debug` to `false` because I was getting a Guzzle error. But in the end it worked :)

Answer (score 13):

For a post call this works for me:

```
$guzzle = new Client(['base_uri' => self::APIURL]);

$raw_response = $guzzle->post($endpoint, [
  'headers' => [ 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $publicKey ],
  'body' => json_encode($data),
]);

$response = $raw_response->getBody()->getContents();
```