# Create function to send requests to an API

Tags: php, api

I have an API that I am trying to create a function for to send requests, the docs are here: http://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/Help

I thought about creating this function in PHP:

```
function jola_api_request($url, $vars = array(), $type = 'POST') {
    $username = '***';
    $password = '***';

    $url = 'https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/'.$url;

    if($type == 'GET') {
        $call_vars = '';
        if(!empty($vars)) {
            foreach($vars as $name => $val) {
                $call_vars.= $name.'='.urlencode($val).'&';
            }
            $url.= '?'.$call_vars;
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // Specify the username and password using the CURLOPT_USERPWD option.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  

    if($type == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }

    // Tell cURL to return the output as a string instead
    // of dumping it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Execute the cURL request.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors.
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        // If an error occured, throw an Exception.
        //throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
        $obj = array('success' => false, 'errors' => curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        $response = json_decode($response);
        $obj = array('success' => true, 'response' => $response);
    }

    return $obj;
}
```

So this determintes whether its a GET or POST request, but the response being returned on some calls is that GET is not supported or POST is not supported, although I am specifying the correct one for each call.

I think I have the function wrong somehow though and wondered if someone could assist me in the right direction? As I've also noticed, I need to allow for DELETE requests too.

Comment: Why not use Guzzle or some sort of tried and tested library to do all the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Have you tried it with postman or a other program to check if the url or the request is correct?

Comment: If the server response "GET is not supported or POST is not supported", then you just simple set wrong HTTP method for APIs

Comment: can you share with us what you use as parameters for your function?

Answer (score 9):

for the easier life, try guzzle.
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

you can make a request like this :

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();
$myAPI = $client->request('GET', 'Your URL goes here');
$myData = json_decode($myAPI->getBody(), true);
```

then you can access the data like an array

```
$myData["Head"][0]
```

Comment: how would i use basic authentication with that?

Comment: @charlie Check the docs. It's dead simple: ```$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);``` - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: can i use `$client->request` to send a post request with body parameters?

Comment: yes you can, just open the docs, it's there http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in `$url` you try to create for GET request.

Your `$url` for GET request looks like:

```
GET https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

but from documentation you can clearly see that you `$url` should be:

```
GET https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/param1/val1/param2
```

for ex.:

```
GET https://simportal-api.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/customers/{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

[GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) is the standard way to work with web service.

You can use `auth` parameter to send your authentication detail. Also, you can use Oath or Beer token whatever your convenient method is. If you try to call service via a token method, keep in mind you will need to pass authorization by **header** instead of `auth`.

See this [GuzzleHttp authentication via token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029422/php-guzzle-with-basic-auth-and-bearer-token?answertab=active#tab-top). Also, you can catch exception very quickly. See [Handle Guzzle exception and get HTTP body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748105/handle-guzzle-exception-and-get-http-body?answertab=active#tab-top)

Try below code got from official site ;)

```
  $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
      'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
  ]);
  echo $res->getStatusCode();
  // "200"
  echo $res->getHeader('content-type')[0];
  // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
  echo $res->getBody();
  // {"type":"User"...'

  // Send an asynchronous request.
  $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
  $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
      echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
  });
  $promise->wait();
```

You can find more about GuzzleHttp request here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request

Hope this what you want!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Postman Tool to request to that API first. If postman does the job it means problem in your PHP code. But if you already used postman and still can't fetch response, so it may be problem with that API. Like URL block.